# Issue on Converting List Items to Lower()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

Using C# language on ASP.Net application I am trying to convert list to Lower by using this line of code:

```
return allResults.ToList<Book>().ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower());
```

but I am getting compiler erro. Can you please let me know how I can fix it?

```
public ICollection<Book> SelectFilteredBooks(){
 using (APPEntities entities = new APPEntities()) {
   try{
   FilterItemList list = (FilterItemList)HttpContext.Current.Session["FilterList"];
          if (list != null)
             {
               Dictionary<String, Object> parameters = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
               String whereParam = FilterItemList.WhereParameter(list.ItemList, "it", ItemType.Book, parameters);
                  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(whereParam))
                      {
                         var allResults = entities.BookS.Where(whereParam);
                         foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> kvp in parameters)
                          {
                   allResults.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));                                 }

                        return allResults.ToList<Book>().ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower());
                           }
                     }
                 }
                 catch (Exception e)
                 {
                      Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                 }
                 return entities.BookS.ToList();
             }
         }
```

Comment: Can you post the compiler error?

Comment: "I am getting compiler erro" is not a good description of what's going wrong.

Comment: `but I am getting compiler erro.` When you ask a question, include the error message and the line you get.

Comment: I am sure you want to convert some of the property of `Book` class. Better to share what are you expecting and the structure of `Book` class

Comment: Side note: there is no need for such a huge sample - first line with exact error would be much better. Showing methods of `Book` class would be add bonus points, especially if you have something like `toLowers()` in that class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting a compiler error because `ToLower()` is not defined on the `Book` class (or at least that's what I'm assuming). In your lambda expression `ToList<Book>().ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower())` `d` is an instance of type `Book`. You probably need something like `d => d.Title.ToLower()` as `ToLower()` is for strings, not books (unless you've defined it yourself but if that were the case you wouldn't be getting compiler errors).

EDIT: From your comment it sounds like you're trying to modify the value of a property for each book. `ConvertAll` isn't really what you want here. Instead try;

```
return allResults.ToList<Book>().ForEach(d => d.Title = d.Title.ToLower());
```

This will basically just loop over your list of Book's applying the lambda expression to each of them.

Comment: Hi evanmcdonnal , thanks for reply actually the d.TITLE.ToLower() was exactly what I was looking for but I am getting this error now Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<BCHANRRWeb.Book>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Behseini ok, I'll put in an edit. I think you should use the `ForEach` operator rather than `ConvertAll`.